# Titanium frame crack

Tags: frames, titanium

I have a one inch crack in the topside centre of my top tube in my Ti bike.
Is this a problem in terms of frame integrity or?
Is it fixable?
The bike was hand built by a local well known frame builder, who is no longer
in the biz

Comment: Add a picture please.

Comment: Can you take a picture, upload to Imgur and add a link to it in your question please. (Someone will edit the picture inline for you, which you wont be able to do until you get some upvotes.)

Comment: It's a bad thing that he's no longer in the business because in a handbuilt frame the damaged tube could be replaced, especially by the guy who built it. If the man's still among the living there's a chance that he might give you a colleagues address. I'd begin there!

Comment: A more significant question is "what caused the crack".

Comment: If the builder is still around, ask their advice.  No framebuilder wants to see their bikes fail.

Comment: It can be tig welded but it’ll never be as strong or confidence inspiring as it was originally before the crack. A lot depends on the grade of the titanium and positioning of the crack also, is it on the weld on the head tube/top tube? and getting advice/info from frame builder is a good idea.

Comment: VTC cos question needs a photo to get useful and relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the best thing to do is to change the frame.
As the builder is no longer in the biz, I guess it will be more difficult to find someone who can fix your frame properly.

You can still ride your bike even with the crack, BUT, the frame is now fragile because of this crack. The crack can grow bigger and bigger with vibrations and at some point, the frame will break on an impact. So you better avoid this case by changing your frame.

Comment: Hard to justify  "you can ride the bike with the crack" when we haven't even seen a photo.

Comment: I agree. Without a photo we don't know if it's either the frame or the paint which is cracked. So, still waiting to see a photo.